# TortoiseGit: Force the "recursive" option to always be on when I clone a repo

Tags: tortoise-git

I'm using TortoiseGit and whenever I clone a repository I want to do it recursively, currently I enable the checkbox for this every time I clone. But sometimes I forget. I was wondering if there's a way to force this checkbox to always be checked?

Comment: At the commandline you could 'alias'  git clone -r  to something like g r  {clone url}   not familiar with TortoiseGit so not sure how that would convert to a gui tool

Comment: See https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2484